# Is there a way to setup multiple cron jobs but with different schedules for same file?

Tags: cron

I have a task which needs to be scheduled for every 15 min from Monday to Friday during Biz hours (UTC time based).

For the same task, I want to reduce the frequency of execution during weekend to 4 hrs.

**For this scenario, cron would be:**

1. `*/15 00-01,12-23 * * 01-05`
2. `* */4 * * 06-07`

Is there anyway to have a single cron instead of two separate cron job? Or can I, in any way, append the two cron jobs into a single one?

Comment: I don't think so. What's the problem with two jobs?

Comment: @BenjaminW: I am using Airflow as scheduling engine which uses cron as scheduler under the hood. For a single DAG, I am trying to setup more controlled schedule